# Get a localStorage item value and set it as a variable

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to get the value of a `localStorage` item (`theme`) and set it as a variable

```js
var theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
```

The `theme` item in my browser is `night` but the `theme` variable is still `dark` from one of my previus tests

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that its Vanilla JS
First you will need to set

`myStorage = window.localStorage;`

then

**For getting Items**
`localStorage.getItem("itemName");`

**For Setting a Item**
`localStorage.setItem("ItemName","ItemValue")`

**For Removing / Deleting the Item**
`localStorage.removeItem("ItemName")`

Answer (score 0):

The localstorage uses plain text, so you have to stringify the data and then parse it.

To save theme:

`localStorage.setItem("theme",JSON.stringify(theme))`

To load theme:

`var theme = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('theme'))`